# How to get only the IP address / subnet

Tags: php, ip, implode

I'm using a jquery plugin, it maskered my field and allow the user only to type the correct values. It is working very well, but now when I submit my form, the object IP is an Array, I need to retrieve only the IP number **(10.1.25.2/30)**

**The result:**

```
$ip = $_POST['ipaddress'];
print_r($ip);

//It returns to me
Array ( [abcd] => Array ( [0] => 10.1.25.2/30 ) )
```

I need implode the Array or do something on this way.. help please.!

**The Whole Code:**

HTML Page **jQuery plugins included:**

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="jquery.validate/jquery.caret.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate/jquery.ipaddress.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $(function(){
        $('#ip').ipaddress({cidr:true});
        });     
    </script>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="equipAction.php">
 <tr>
  <td>IP</td>
  <td><input name="ipaddress[abcd][]" id="ip" type="text" value="<?=$ip;?>" />
  <b>»» IP atribuído ao contrato do Cliente/Torre </b> </td>    
 </tr>
 <input type='submit' name="alt" value="Edit" class="btn" />
</form>
```

**Now my Action php code:**

```
 if ($_POST["alt"] == "Edit") {

    # Dados do form
    $idequip  = $_GET['id'];
    $contrato = $_POST['contrato'];
    $transmi  = $_POST['transmissor'];
    $ip       = $_POST['ipaddress'];
    $local    = $_POST['local']; //tipo_equip
    $obs      = $_POST['obs'];
    $usado    = $_POST['usado'];

    echo "<br />";
    print_r($ip);




    # Atualiza dados do equipamento mestre
    # desenvolvendo
    $res = mysql_query("UPDATE equipment SET idtorre='$transmi', ip='$ip', tipo_equip='$local', obs='$obs', usado_cliente='$usado' WHERE id='$idequip'") or die("Erro na query: atualização equipamento mestre.");
    #header("Location: equipamento_adm.php?return=3&ip=$control");
    exit;
 }
```

That all!

Comment: Could you please post your HTML and JavaScript code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It a simple multidimensional array, you can retrieve your value like this :

```
$ip = $_POST['ipaddress'];    
$justip = $ip['abcd'][0];
```

Now there's only the ip address in the `$justip` variable.

You should maybe read the documentation about arrays : http://ch.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: `$ip = $_POST['ipaddress']['abcd'][0]`

Comment: Gotcha! I works fine that's it man. Perheaps cause it is an multidimensional array I had confuse myself.. I have been working long time with stuffs like.. Oh! shameful.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How many forms are on this page?

The reason that it's showing up in an array and not in $_POST['ipaddress'] is this: `<input name="ipaddress[abcd][]" id="ip" type="text" value="<?=$ip;?>" />` in the form html.  The `[abcd][]` causes it to make ipaddress an array containing an array with a key of 'abcd' of which the first available key gets populated with the value from the form.  If you did `<input name="ipaddress" id="ip" type="text" value="<?=$ip;?>" />` then the IP address would be available directly through `$_POST['ipaddress']`.

If you have multiple forms, then use `name="ipaddress[]"` and each form will populate a key of the `$_POST['ipaddress']` array, so `$_POST['ipaddress'][0]` will be the first form and `$_POST['ipaddress'][1]` will be the second form and so on.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you switch from

```
<input name="ipaddress[abcd][]" id="ip" type="text" value="<?=$ip;?>" />
```

to

```
<input name="ipaddress[abcd]" id="ip" type="text" value="<?=$ip;?>" />
```

you will get rid of the array (notice the removed `[]` from the input's name attribute).