# IP and subnet of users

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can I get the IP and subnet of any user who access my site 
for example if a user come to my index page.. Can i have a function in my index which can get me the IP and subnet of that user ?

The IP and subnet should look like this

```
217.194.65.0/27
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can maybe look at this comment on PHP.Net http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php#94290

Comment: Check out this post.. maybe it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181133/how-to-get-only-the-ip-address-subnet

Answer (score 0):

To get the subnet out of an IP address, you need the network mask first.

This information relies on your visitor network infrastructure and I don't think you can get this information easily.

One option would be to do a lookup in the ARIN (assuming the range was originally allocated by ARIN) database to know how the network is divided.

http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-8-8-8-0-1/pft

You can see the initial allocation subnet under CIDR, but this might differ from the actual network division made by Google, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

i think [this link](http://www.linglom.com/2007/02/20/how-to-find-subnet-number-ip-addresses-in-the-subnet-in-a-few-seconds/) will help you to calculate the subnet from the ip

for finding ip

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: your link describes a BAD practice, by using code like `$ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];`. Variables provided by client (HTTP_) should never be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

http://pear.php.net/package/Net_IPv4

That, among other packages in pear (such as IPv6, CheckIP2, etc) may be of use to you for getting that type of information